# Тестирование Android приложения. Как получить доступ к логам?

Tags: android, логирование

Мой заказчик "тестирует" промежуточную сборку приложения на своём устройстве. У него вылетает баг, который я не могу отловить. Подскажите, как я могу получить лог с устройства заказчика? Со всеми exception'ми?

Я пробовала установить CatLog и Log collrctor. Но эти приложения отлавливают какой-то общий системный лог, а не лог моего приложения.

Comment: А включить отладку на устройстве заказчика, и нормально отладить там приложение - не вариант?

Comment: заказчик удаленно находится

Comment: Тогда без рута, к сожалению, удаленной отладки не выйдет. Попробуйте правда какой-нибудь агрегатор исключений подключить, как ниже советуют.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На android > 4.2 CatLog и Log collector могут получить доступ к логам вашего приложения только на рутованном устройстве.

Можно встроить в приложение библиотеку для сбора отчетов об ошибках, например, [Acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Но проще будет воспользоваться спец. сервисом для тестирования: HockeyApp, Appaloosa, Store, Apphance, и т.п.

Comment: а как сделать устройство рутованным?

Comment: Для каждой модели устройства процесс индивидуальный и это лишает гарантии. Зарегистрируйтесь лучше на каком-нибудь сервисе :)